# How to make a web based appliaction to call on cell phone

Tags: php

I want to make a web page in PHP from there users can easily call to any mobile numbers how is this possible in PHP?

Comment: wait for php10, it will have the long-awaited `pmagic_callcellphone("123-123434");` function.

Comment: I m sure you are making this compiler. good revolution. great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something similar to [Google Talk Developer API](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html) with the [libjingle](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/) kit.

(Considering that's about as close to voice and calls you'll get to without finding a company with a phone number and SDK--Google voice I don't think has an SDK).

Additionally, you could Google ["VOIP SDK"](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+telephone&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=drL&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&q=voip+sdk&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=b5fc6a07c812d0bf) and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need synchronous voice communication (i.e.: a pre-recorded message is fine) then [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) has a wonderful HTTP API for interfacing with telephones.